# Android listview widget not showing elements

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to create a simple widget in Android to display a list of elements

```
public class calendarWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private View setContentView(int calendar_widget) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onEnabled(Context context) {

        List<String> elementList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
            elementList.add("Element " + i);
        }

        View calendarView = setContentView(R.layout.calendar_widget);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<> (context,
                R.layout.calendar_widget, elementList);

        ListView listView = (ListView) calendarView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

The code creates an array with 15 elements. I would like to show the elements it in a listview (one element for each cell).

The output unfortunately looks like this

[output on a real android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow7Ug.jpg)

does anyone know where do the problem is ?

edit:

calendar_widget.xml contains:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/Widget.AppName.AppWidget.Container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppWidgetContainer">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: App Widgets are quite a bit different than Activities. You cannot directly access `View`s because they are running in another app's process. You have to build and manipulate your UI through `RemoteViews`, and it gets even more complicated when you need a collection widget like a `ListView`. You might have a look through [this developer page](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets) for the basics, and then [this one](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets/collections) for the additional stuff that would be necessary for your `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Set adapter like this and check it again

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}}, 100);
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I am debugging the code. I received the following error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference